# Observe array with Proxy (adding and removing items)

Tags: javascript, arrays, es6-proxy

I'm playing around with Proxys and my goal is to obeserve operations on some array. In particular I want to run some code whenever items are being added or removed. The [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwNYFMAKAnEAPAnjAXhgApsIAuGBMXAbQF0BKQgPgCgYYwUB3GTHLlIQANDADeHTjAgooxBBgwJcYgA5Y1YgG4IANgFcUYjCmAoAltpQZmk6dNCQQelADo9IAObEABgGU5GAAScX8oDAswHw0QNUYAXxgAWhYQ8V1DFATfRgBuKQcnCBd3Tx8AIgJqmtqK-LZC6VMoAwwwGAAlFAAzV2AoN1l5RWVVGFitGEyjEzNLa1sChwSRJoATFFcodE0bKCFRlXVNOybOYtKPbz8AES25FHTwyOjiScSYAB90o7pJ+g5BoOC7gEqua6VWrQgj1ArnGAtNodbp9MyDTbbXZxfaHJTHCanZbSVZSBINNjFWBkQjwZDYvDEBgUshuNQGCAAC2IAEYAAxiABMApgAGYRQAWPkNVkQNR6CzmYginkyiBDTkWHryCmXCHlYQNIA) that I currently have is the following:

```js
const makeProxy = (xs) =>
  new Proxy(xs, {
    set(array, prop, value, receiver) {
      console.log(`Set ${String(prop)} -> ${value}`);
      return Reflect.set(array, prop, value, receiver);
    },
    deleteProperty(array, prop) {
      console.log(`Delete ${String(prop)} | ${array[prop]}`);
      return Reflect.deleteProperty(array, prop);
    },
  });

const xs = makeProxy([]);

xs.push(10, 20, 30, 40);
console.log("==========");
xs.splice(0, 1);
console.log("==========");
xs.shift();
console.log("==========");

console.log(xs);
```

The question I have has to do with the `deleteProperty` part of the Proxy. When calling methods like `splice` and `shift` on the array I really want to know what elements will be removed. Is there a nice way of doing this? In the `deleteProperty` method I don't seem to have the necessary information, perhaps it is not the right place?

Comment: Overwrite the `shift` and `splice` methods with ones that do what you want. From the logs it should be clear what these methods are doing to the array, and why the proxy traps don't have the information you want.

Comment: Well yes it seems that the values are being shifted to the left and the end is thrown out. But is there way of observing this with a Proxy while knowing what gets removed?

Comment: No, not from within the `set` and `deleteProperty` traps of the proxy.

Comment: Neet piece of code, thanks for posting. Works fine for me.